# Calculate distance of point along a line using NetTopologySuite

Tags: nettopologysuite

I am looking to calculate the distance along a line of a point using NetTopologySuite.

Indications are that the distanceOp may have something to do with it, given that I can a point on a line closest to another geometry.  However how to determine the distance along the line of that point?  I can certainly determine what that distance is myself through some code - but I would have through NTS would already have this covered off.

Anyone have any pointers?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 3):

**[LinearReferencing.LengthLocationMap](http://code.google.com/p/nettopologysuite/source/browse/trunk/NetTopologySuite/LinearReferencing/LengthLocationMap.cs?r=790)** will get you the distance of point along a line.

> Computes the LinearLocation for a given length along a linear
>   Geometry.Negative lengths are measured in reverse from end of the
>   linear geometry. Out-of-range values are clamped.

```cs
using NetTopologySuite.LinearReferencing;

string wkt = "LINESTRING (0 0, 10 0, 10 10)";
WKTReader rdr = new WKTReader();
IGeometry g1 = rdr.Read(wkt);

ILineString linearGeometry = (ILineString)g1;
Coordinate pt = new Coordinate(10,5);
LinearLocation linearLocation = LocationIndexOfPoint.IndexOf(linearGeometry, pt);
double length = LengthLocationMap.GetLength(linearGeometry, linearLocation);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use the JTS/NTS APIs much myself but I would look at the [`LengthIndexedLine`](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/linearref/LengthIndexedLine.html) class:

> Supports linear referencing along a linear [`Geometry`](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry.html) using the length along the line as the index. Negative length values are taken as measured in the reverse direction from the end of the geometry. Out-of-range index values are handled by clamping them to the valid range of values. Non-simple lines (i.e. which loop back to cross or touch themselves) are supported.

Particularly, look at the [`project`](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/linearref/LengthIndexedLine.html#project%28com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate%29) method:

> Computes the index for the closest point on the line to the given
>   point. If more than one point has the closest distance the first one
>   along the line is returned. (The point does not necessarily have to
>   lie precisely on the line.)

I am assuming that the value returned is the actual length along the line to that point. I could be off base though, as I haven't tried it.